# How do you get the world position of the tail end of the bone without a child bone in threejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js, 3d

If I wanted to get the world position of the head end of the bone, it would be:

```
let worldpos_head_x = skinnedMesh.skeleton.bones[111].matrixWorld.elements[12]
let worldpos_head_y = skinnedMesh.skeleton.bones[111].matrixWorld.elements[13]
let worldpos_head_z = skinnedMesh.skeleton.bones[111].matrixWorld.elements[14]
```

To get the tail end of this bone, I could just get the head position of the child.
But how do I get the world position of the tail end that doesn't have any children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bone position is defined by its spatial relation to any parent. After factoring in constraints of rotation or IK, the bone's position is still a coordinate. If the bone is uncoupled from the parent, it is still a coordinate. Traverse the children array until the length is 0 and that is the end.

To your point, in JavaScript you may publicly traverse and extend the object prototype... for example, use BVH raytracing to project the bone vector. Then you could see that:

```
let eyeGouge = fingerbone.raymarch(eyeMesh);
```